# When restarting Spring Boot I see 'no profiles are currently active'

Tags: java, spring-boot

My Spring Boot version is 2.3.4-RELEASE. I configure DataSource this way in application-dev.yml:

```
spring:
  profiles: dev
  datasource:
    master:
      driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
      url: myUrl
    slave:
      driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
      url: myUrl
```

When I activate the 'dev' profile, I can start my Spring Boot container successfully, but when I restart it, I get this error:

> Description:
> Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and
> no embedded datasource could be configured.
>
> Reason:
> Failed to determine a suitable driver class
>
> Action:
> Consider the following:
> If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
> If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently
> active).

I tried to add the config: *spring.datasource.url*. It works, but I need to distinguish master and slave. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

You must activate your profile using property `spring.profiles.active`

> If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile
> you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).

Read [set the active Spring profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.0.M1/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html#howto-set-active-spring-profiles) to see how to do it